# Windows authentification to SQL Server authentification

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, authentication

How to change login name from Windows authentification to SQL Server authentification?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change a Windows login to a SQL login. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql) states:

> SQL Server authentication logins are type sysname and must conform to
>   the rules for Identifiers and cannot contain a '\'.

Since the Windows login name contains '\' to separate the domain and user name, you will need to create a new login for SQL authentication and assign a password.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to change a Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login to a SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login.

One reason being that a Windows Authenticated SQL Server Logins retrieves the SID from Active Directory and stores it in the master database. Another reason is that the backslash (`\`) is not a valid character for a SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login.

> ```
> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
> ------------------------------
> Create failed for Login 'Domain\User'.  
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
> ...
> ------------------------------
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
> ------------------------------
> 'Domain\User' is not a valid name because it contains invalid characters.
> (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15006)
> ....
> ------------------------------
> BUTTONS:
> OK
> ------------------------------
> ```

There are a couple of solutions to your problem, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

#### 1. Create a New SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login

You can create a new SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login and assign it a password and the relevant database permissions. This account shouldn't contain a backslash ( `\` ) because of the above limitations.

#### 2. Map the Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login to an Existing Database User

Instead of creating a new SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login, you can link the existing Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login to either an existing Database User that has not yet been linked or to a new non-existing Database User. To achieve this using the GUI in SSMS you

- expand the **Security** branch
- expand the **Logins** branch
- select your user (e.g. `NewComputer\User`)
- open the properties of the user
- switch to the **User Mapping** section
- select the relevant database
- in the **User** column insert an existing Database User that has not yet been linked to a SQL Server Login (These can be found in the Datbase\Security\Users branch in SSMS)

This will link the Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login to an existing SQL Server Database User.

#### 3. Drop the Existing Windows Authenticate SQL Server Login and Recreate

If you require the user's name to be the same as what you previously defined as your Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login, then you will have to drop SQL Serer Login and re-create it, but without the backslash. This user can then be linked to the database.

#### 4. Login Issues

If the reason for wanting to switch from a Windows Authenticated SQL Server Login to a SQL Server Authenticated SQL Server Login is login issue, then you might want to consider starting the program with the Windows Account that has access to the database, which will then allow you to connect to the database. To achieve this follow these steps:

1. Start the program with **Runas different user...**
2. Enter the Windows Credentials
3. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can change login types once a login exists, you would need to drop it and recreate.

Note that you can not have a SQL authentication login with a name of the form `something\somethingelse` because slash characters are not valid in usernames. You can have domain and SQL users with the same name because `somedomain\username`, `localmachine\username`, and `username` would not conflict - so you can create `user` as a SQL login without needing to drop `localmachine\user` first.

Answer (score 0):

The characted '\' will be identified as invalid character and it will error out if you try to create a SQL login using it. This is not possible.

First of all please go through the two types of authentication and how that works. Windows Authentication is for AD users which goes by Domain\user_name and are added to the instance while SQL Authentication is for logins created inside the instance. Please go through the below link :
[Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server)